# MySQL query to MDB query

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I want to convert the following MySQL to MDB query. I am not at all familiar with access and .mdb databases but I have no choice on this project. I have set up the database in .mdb and can make simple queries to it.
I am trying to convert the following query to mdb query.

```
SELECT name
       , lat
       , lng
       , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('21.222') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
       * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('44.333') ) 
       + sin( radians('21.222') ) 
       * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < '25' 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

The query is basically querying a table markers with latitute , longitude information for each record and returns the place which is within *25* miles of the dummy place with latitude,longitude as (*21.222,44.333*)

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: BTW: You can make SQL queries changing the query edit from structure to SQL - you are aware of that right? Check [this](http://pcmcourseware.com/blog/2008/09/17/creating-asql-query-in-access-2007/) out.

Comment: I am querying the .mdb file from a PHP script, The link above does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create your own functions for those built in MySQL Mathematic functions, since access won't recognize them.  Also the TOP 1 syntax is slightly different.  These functions will be only available within the access application itself, so you might have to get really creative how to call this from your PHP script.

Put these math functions into a VBA code module:

```
Public Function acos(x As Double) As Double
'gets the inverse cosine

    acos = Atn(-x / Sqr(-x * x + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1)
End Function

Public Function cos(x As Double) As Double
'gets the cosine

    cos = Math.cos(x)
End Function

Public Function radians(degrees As Double) As Double
'returns a degrees measure in radians

    Const PI = 3.1415926535

    radians = degrees * PI / 180
End Function

Public Function sin(x As Double) As Double
'gets the sine

    sin = Math.sin(x)
End Function
```

Your Access SQL query will look like this (Built using the query builder):

```
SELECT TOP 1 markers.name, markers.lat, markers.lng, (3959*acos(Cos(radians(21.222))*Cos(radians([lat]))*Cos(radians([lng])-radians(44.333))+Sin(radians(21.222))*Sin(radians([lat])))) AS distance

FROM markers

GROUP BY markers.name, markers.lat, markers.lng, (3959*acos(Cos(radians(21.222))*Cos(radians([lat]))*Cos(radians([lng])-radians(44.333))+Sin(radians(21.222))*Sin(radians([lat]))))

HAVING ((((3959*acos(Cos(radians(21.222))*Cos(radians([lat]))*Cos(radians([lng])-radians(44.333))+Sin(radians(21.222))*Sin(radians([lat])))))<25))

ORDER BY (3959*acos(Cos(radians(21.222))*Cos(radians([lat]))*Cos(radians([lng])-radians(44.333))+Sin(radians(21.222))*Sin(radians([lat]))));
```